# jenkins doesn't have rights to copy files - or does it?

Tags: jenkins

I have a strange problem in jenkins, I cannot copy files in a job, however, with the user jenkins on the command line, I can do that without problem.

I am using jenkins on debian running under the user "jenkins".

I added the user "jenkins" to the group "www-data", so that I can copy files to the www-folder of apache.

The folder rights of the target folder look like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x 9 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 23 16:19 .   
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 23 12:45 ..  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 volker   www-data  368 Jun 23 17:10 about.php  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 volker   www-data  366 Jun 23 17:10 bio.php  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 volker   www-data  370 Jun 23 17:10 contact.php   
drwxrwxr-x 3 volker   www-data 4096 Jun 23 16:19 content  
drwxrwxr-x 3 volker   www-data 4096 Jun 23 16:19 css  
drwxrwxr-x 8 volker   www-data 4096 Jun 23 16:19 default  
drwxrwxr-x 3 volker   www-data 4096 Jun 23 16:19 fonts  
drwxrwxr-x 2 volker   www-data 4096 Jun 23 13:40 image  
drwxrwxr-x 3 volker   www-data 4096 Jun 23 16:19 images  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 volker   www-data  372 Jun 23 17:10 impressum.php  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 volker   www-data  367 Jun 23 17:10 index.php  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 volker   www-data  296 Jun 23 13:52 kontakt.php  
drwxrwxr-x 3 volker   www-data 4096 Jun 23 16:19 layout   
-rw-rw-r-- 1 volker   www-data  367 Jun 23 17:10 news.php  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 volker   www-data  370 Jun 23 17:10 termine.php  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 volker   www-data  369 Jun 23 17:10 videos.php
```

So everything is writable for group www-data.

If I am using the jenkins user to copy the files in the shell, I get no error:

```
jenkins@rootserver:~/jobs/deploy_notundellende/workspace$ whoami  
jenkins  
jenkins@rootserver:~/jobs/deploy_notundellende/workspace$ cp -R * /var/www/nue  
jenkins@rootserver:~/jobs/deploy_notundellende/workspace$
```

But if I use the same command in jenkins itself, it fails with permission error:

```
pwd  
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/deploy_notundellende/workspace  
whoami  
jenkins  
cp -R about.php bio.php contact.php content css fonts images impressum.php index.php   layout news.php termine.php videos.php /var/www/nue  
cp: cannot create regular file `/var/www/nue/about.php': Permission denied  
cp: cannot create regular file `/var/www/nue/bio.php': Permission denied  
cp: cannot create regular file `/var/www/nue/contact.php': Permission denied  
cp: cannot create regular file `/var/www/nue/content/videos.php': Permission denied
```

How is that possible? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: OK, I got it to work, I restarted the jenkins server and it worked.
I assume it did not work before, because the jenkins server was already running when I changed its permissions.
Makes sense to me now, come to think of it :)
Anyway, thanks for anybody reading and thinking about this!

Comment: provide that as an answer and accept that. That's the way stackoverflow marks a question as resolved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, I got it to work, I restarted the jenkins server and it worked. I assume it did not work before, because the jenkins server was already running when I changed its permissions. Makes sense to me now, come to think of it :) Anyway, thanks for anybody reading and thinking about this!

Comment: Thanks! Jeeez what a simple solution to a terrible problem XD

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** Restart Jenkins

`(jenkins_url)/safeRestart` - Allows all running jobs to complete. New jobs will remain in the queue to run after the restart is complete.

`(jenkins_url)/restart` - Forces a restart without waiting for builds to complete.

**Solution 2:** Check the user and permission for the same user

Check user:  `whoami`

change permission: `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/*` or `sudo chmod a+rwx /var/szDirectoryName`

**Solution 3:**

If you get error/warning like [Linux: 'Username' is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported ref the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806576/linux-username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-this-incident-will-be-reported)