# "'Username' is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported"

Tags: linux, sudoers

After logging into ssh in a Linux machine, I got this message:

> 'Username' is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.

How can I resolve this? I'm connecting ssh to my virtual private server.

I need to have sudoers privilegies.

Comment: do your user have admin access? If  no then login with root and add your user to `/etc/sudoers` file

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179954/username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-this-incident-will-be-reported

Comment: And https://askubuntu.com/questions/2214/how-do-i-add-a-user-to-the-sudo-group   And https://superuser.com/questions/866582/username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-this-incident-will-be-reported

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Open file

```
su root 
nano /etc/sudoers
```

Then add the user below admin user like below syntax.

```
user_name ALL=(ALL)  ALL
```

Comment: Recommended way is to use `visudo` to avoid simultaneous edits (possibly not a problem in this case, but still...)

Comment: It's only what the comment at the very top of the file makes clear `"## This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root."`

Comment: How does this make sense? The issue is that the user can't use sudo, so how can part of the solution be using sudo?

Comment: Found that following in one of a video. It worked for me. 

Given that, we need to be in root mode. 

For that, ssh root@localhost, then sudo nano /etc/sudoers

Comment: I dont like this answer. It should explain more than, this should be done through root user but he left that information making people confused.

Comment: @KansaiRobot You cannot su root if the user is not in the list of sudoers file

Comment: Even though sudo was not working for any other commands after an unattended install, `su root` did work, and after I was root I just ran `usermod -a -G sudo myusername` and it worked.

Answer (score 85):

Both the above answers are correct as far as they go but it is easier to add your user to the sudo group in debian based systems (Ubuntu, kbuntu, debian, etc)  and the wheel group under RedHat based systems (RedHat, Fedora, CentOS, etc)

```bash
usermod -a -G sudo user
# or
usermod -a -G wheel user
```

Comment: Exaaaactly. Include OpenSuse under the 2nd group. In my case I I reversed the order, modifying `sudoers` before adding my user to `wheel` and ended up here.

Comment: It's too much better this way, because you don't need edit none critical files for make this operation.

Comment: Didn't worked on my Ubuntu 22.04 by on [Contabo](https://contabo.com/)

Comment: @Mahesh User's process tree may need to be restarted.

Comment: It triggers the `Permission denied` issue.

Comment: usermod: command not found.

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-user-to-group-in-linux/

Comment: @konsolebox yeah, it worked after I logged-out and then logged-in as the user

Comment: usermod: command not found.  is there a package for this?

Answer (score 42):

This is a very common error for the beginners.
The error occurs because we are trying to access/update something with super privileges from the user instead of root -user.

Hence, to solve this,we need to make changes in the sudoers file where the root user has been given the privileges. So, switch to root user,run the following command

```
sudo su 
# vi /etc/sudoers
```

The editor would open the file, now scroll down to the bottom where you will see a line

```
#User privilege specification

root     ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

username ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

As you can see, I have just added my username with all permissions.

Save the file, and exit. Switch back to the user and start using sudo commands with ease.

Answer (score 11):

At the top of the aforementioned `/etc/sudoers` file there's an info:

```
"## This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root."
```

In order of doing as we're told, use:

```
$ su
> Enter root password: *******
$ visudo -f /etc/sudoers
```

Find the following section of `/etc/sudoers` file and add your users privileges:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
user_name ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Save the file (press <kbd>esc</kbd> and type `:x` if vim is your default text editor, for nano press <kbd>ctrl+o</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl+x</kbd>).

Type `exit` to turn off the `root` shell, and enjoy the power of `sudo` with your `username`

Answer (score 8):

You should use `visudo` to edit /etc/sudoers file.

Just run
`sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers`

and add your username with correct syntax and access rights.
You can find more in `man sudoers`

Answer (score 7):

Got a slightly different syntax to Rodney's from my host

```
usermod -aG wheel username
```

Their explanation was

> The user will need to be added to the wheel group.
>
> Use the usermod command to add the user to the wheel group.

You may need to log off and log back in after doing this

Comment: I simply needed to log off and log back in after applying this solution.

Comment: What if my user already belongs to the wheel group but I still get "'Username' is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported."?

Comment: @AdrianLopez the wheel syntax only makes sense if wheel is a sudoers group, which in your case it probably isn't. This answer is also not really helpful, but rather miss informing to be honest. By default wheel isn't in the sudoers file.

Answer (score 7):

1. Entered Root using command `$ su root`. Input Root Password
2. Install sudo: `$ apt-get install sudo -y`
3. Add your < username> `$ adduser <username> sudo`
4. `$ exit`
5. Then sign up and sign in the < username> session
6. Finally, check with: `< username>@< hostname>:~$ sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 6):

If you're unable to find visudo on your system

```
whereis visudo
```

Launch this tool

```
./PATH/visudo
```

add this line under

> User privilege specification

```
user_name ALL=(ALL)  ALL
```

Save the changes and here you go !

Answer (score 4):

First, switch/ log into the root user account or an account that has sudo privileges.

Next add the user to the group for sudo users:

- If you're on **Ubuntu** members of the **sudo** group are granted with sudo privileges, so you can use this:

  ```
  sudo adduser username sudo
  ```
- If you're on **CentOS**  members of the **wheel** group are granted with sudo privileges, so you can use this::

  ```
  usermod -aG wheel username
  ```

**Note**: Replace username with your desired `username`.

To test the sudo access, log into the account that you just added to the sudo users grouP, and then run the command below using `sudo`:

```
sudo whoami
```

You will be prompted to enter the password. If the user have sudo access, the output will be:

```
root
```

If you get an error saying **user is not in the sudoers file**, it means that the user doesn’t have sudo privileges yet.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 4):

[try this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_h-yOQx0X04&ab_channel=AmbarHasbiyatmoko), it works for me.

1. ssh root@localhost
2. sudo vi /etc/sudoers
3. insert username in file 'sudoers'
4. save and exit ssh

Answer (score 1):

Add your user to the list of sudoers. This will make it easier to execute
commands as the user that you have created will require admin privileges.

```
sudo adduser username sudo
```

Note: `username` is the user you want to give the privileges to.

Comment: this won't work if the user can't use sudo which is what the original poster can't do hence the error message.