# Getting error "User is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported."

Tags: macos, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, sudoers

I'm trying to install GitLab Runner on Mac with manual installation, but after entering the first command:

```
sudo curl --output /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-runner-darwin-amd64
```

I get the following error:

> User is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: Have you checked [How to solve “User is not in sudoers file, incident reported”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/190883/253138) over at [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Username' is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806576/username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-this-incident-will-be-reported)

Answer (score 0):

I managed a similar problem (install Cocoapods) by adding to my user the admin rights.
Go to Settings -> Users -> Click "User is allowed to admin this computer". After a restart, it should work again.