# java -version giving error in Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.3

Tags: java, linux, unix, rhel, java-6

I have installed jdk1.6 in my RHEL 8.3 OS , and changed the JAVA_HOME to point to this folder.

However, if i do a java -version, it shows below error :

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Have restarted the putty session but still the issue persists.
Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```bash
sudo dnf install libnsl
```

As **Martin Zeitler** said, if your `JDK` is 32 bits, it can be:

```bash
sudo dnf install libnsl.i686
```

But if your `JDK` is 64 bits, the command is:

```bash
sudo dnf install libnsl.x86_64
```

The problem is that the command `java -version` fails, so we can't see if the architecture is 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: This might be `libnsl.i686`? `dnf whatprovides */libnsl.so.1`.

Comment: "username" is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
Seems like root privileges are required..

Comment: @Shubham Uniyal, This occurs when you use the command `sudo` and you are not an admin. Ask an admin to complete this installation task.

Comment: @Shubham Uniyal, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806576/linux-username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-this-incident-will-be-reported